# ペイパルの定期支払のIPNについて

Tags: paypal

未決済分を次月へ繰り越した場合、次月の決済通知(IPN)は2ヶ月分の決済が一度に発生したように通知されるのか？
（1ヶ月分500円の場合、1,000円決済される）
または、500円の決済が2回発生するのか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

未決済分を含む次月の決済が成功した場合のIPNは以下のようになります。

mc_gross=1000 // 決済総額
outstanding_balance=0 //決済が成功したので繰越残高が0円になります。
amount=500 //定期支払い金額
amount_per_cycle=500 //定期支払い金額

outstanding_balance は繰越残高がある場合にその金額が設定されますので、この例の場合は、失敗した月のIPNに outstanding_balance=500 が含まれます。